# Using linq any to check if contains in list

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, filter

Here I have list of jurisdictions stored in a list.

Lets say the object jurisdictions contains 9 items returning refs 1-9
My other object filter.Jurisdictions contains 2 items returning ref 1 and ref 2.

I do not want to return rows where if a ref exists in jurisdictions but does not exist in filter.jurisdictions. As refs 1 and 2 from filter.jurisidctions is contained in the jurisdictions object, it should return just 2 rows and not 9 (as it's returning right now)

Hope this makes sense. 
Here is the code:

```
var jurisdictions = trackAnalyticsService.GetJurisdictions(new Track.TrackDataFilter(new int[] { companyId }, null, from, to, userFirmRef), maxJurisdictions);
-- returns 9 rows

if (filter?.Jurisdictions.Count() > 0)
    jurisdictions.Where(tag => filter.Jurisdictions.Any(x => x == tag.Ref));
-- jurisidctions should now be filtered to just 2 rows as filter.Jurisidction ref 1 and 2 is contained in jurisdictions and none of the other refs.
```

thanks

Comment: I assume your code does not work.  Can you please tell us the exact problem.  Please include any error messages or the expected and actual results of your code.

Comment: Why even have the `Count()` check?

Answer (score 0):

the linq code assigns the new values to another value, not update the original collection

```
if (filter?.Jurisdictions.Count() > 0){
     var updatedJurisdictions =jurisdictions.Where(tag => filter.Jurisdictions.Any(x => x == tag.Ref)).ToList(); // or whatever
}
```

Edited: Removed .Select() as it wasn't needed

Comment: `select(x=>x)` doesnt do anything, just leave it out

Comment: you're right, i was doing this off the top of my head.  Thanks